# Leitura de PDF - PHP - Conteudo e ID

Tags: php, pdf

Estou procurando uma solução que consiste em uma forma automática de leitura de PDF's, basicamente recebo centenas de faturas e queria uma forma de automatizar.
O que tentei:

> Programas que converte em txt, o que não é tão eficaz porque bagunça alguns valores
>
> Programas que pega pela coordenada, algumas vezes muda de
> coordenada x,y, por exemplo, normalmente um trecho de PDF tem uma
> linha, mas algumas vezes quando tem dois, zoa o layout.

Estou tentando encontrar algum padrão, talvez como um ID, li esta documentação http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php queria ver se pegaria o dicionário, de repente o valor que eu quero, em todas as faturas ficariam com o mesmo dicionário.
Alguem tem alguma ideia de alguma biblioteca que eu poderia resgatar o dicionário e o texto?
Acredito que a biblioteca mais completa é a PDFParser - pdfparser.org que suporta mais encoding e o máximo que tem suporte é extrair metadata